# Saving file as .m causes it to save as comments

Tags: packages, save

I am attempting to create a `Package` and so am saving a notebook with the code from Mathematica's example

```
BeginPackage["Collatz`"]

Collatz::usage = "Collatz[n] gives a list of the iterates in the 3n+1 \
problem,
         starting from n. The conjecture is that this sequence always
         terminates."

Begin["`Private`"]

Collatz[1] := {1}

Collatz[n_Integer] := Prepend[Collatz[3 n + 1], n] /; OddQ[n] && n > 0

Collatz[n_Integer] := Prepend[Collatz[n/2], n] /; EvenQ[n] && n > 0

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

And save it as a .m file. However, when I try to `Get` the file it doesn't work. So I did `FilePrint` as in their example and everything is commented.

```
Get["Desktop\Collatz.m"]

(* ::Package:: *)

(* ::Input:: *)
(*BeginPackage["Collatz`"]*)
(**)
(*Collatz::usage="Collatz[n] gives a list of the iterates in the 3n+1 problem,*)
(*        starting from n. The conjecture is that this sequence always*)
(*        terminates."*)
(**)
(*Begin["`Private`"]*)
(**)
(*Collatz[1]:={1}*)
(**)
(*Collatz[n_Integer]:=Prepend[Collatz[3 n+1],n]/;OddQ[n]&&n>0*)
(**)
(*Collatz[n_Integer]:=Prepend[Collatz[n/2],n]/;EvenQ[n]&&n>0*)
(**)
(*End[]*)
(**)
(*EndPackage[]*)
```

Am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: The solution is to convert the relevant cells into initialization cells...

Comment: It is unclear how a Section or Subsection that is an 'Initialization Group' passes its state to cells within it. And it is unclear how text cells (Alt-7) are handled when within such a cell. It appears that Cell Properties Evaluatable makes text cells inside of an Initialization Group get saved verbatim, which makes the resulting *.m file un-loadable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only initialization cells will be saved as uncommented code.

Check Cell -> Cell Properties -> Initialization Cell and Initialization Group.

You can also use Code cells (instead of Input), which have the Initialization Cell property by default.  Alt-8 or Command-8 inserts a code cell.

You can check that it is an initialization cell by looking at the top right corner of the cell which has an extra cross:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Anything which is not an initialization cell will be commented out.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer explains well why this happens and what you can do to fix it. One thing you can do when writing a package is first create a blank text file with the .m or .wl file extension, and then open it up in *Mathematica*.

The file is interpreted as a package, not a notebook, and so

- Any new cell created is an initialization cell, no need to create a special cell or modify cell properties.
- When saved, all cells are written to the file as plain text
- Output cells are not written to the file.