# .m files saving with comments

Tags: packages, initialization, comment

So I have posted a few questions on loading packages, because it is so simple, yet always failing for me. I made a new file Streams.m in the directory ~/Library/Mathematica/Applications/, which is in `$Path`. This is the same directory in which Classes.m is in, which works and loads fully. I know that the command `<<` reads in a file, and I am fairly certain I have figured out what has been causing these frustrating errors. When I open Classes.m and Streams.m in Mathematica, they look normal, nothing commented out.
However, when I open Classes.m and Streams.m in vim, I get this:
[image]
[image]
So I think it's pretty clear the reason I can load the Streams.m but not use the functions is because of the commenting, but I absolutely did not save it that way. Any ideas why it would save like this? Another odd difference is that Classes.m starts with ::Input::Initialization:: while Streams.m just starts with ::Input::. Furthermore, if I add ::Initialization:: to Streams.m and then open it, I get this:[image]
What on earth is going on? When I create these files, I type them up in a blank notebook then do save as, and choose .m extension. Do I really have to manually go through in vim and uncomment everything? This will just happen again when I make a new package.

Comment: When you create a package from a notebook, any cell that isn't an "Initialization" cell will become a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving file as .m causes it to save as comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89844/saving-file-as-m-causes-it-to-save-as-comments)

Comment: jeez is it that simple lol? I undid all the comments in vim and it works. Must've been that. why must it be an initialization cell?

Comment: I think the workflow is that you develop a package in a notebook, but there could be all kinds of random cells in there.  So you take the cells that represent the actual package code and make them Initialization cells.  I don't make packages that way, but that seems what it is made for

Comment: how do you make packages?

Comment: I prototype functions in a notebook until they work the way I like, then I copy them over to the package code where I use a text editor.  There are plugins for popular editors like Eclipse, JetBrains, or VSCode that make writing Wolfram Language code easier.

Comment: I think this question will be closed as duplicate, but I came up with a nice workaround that allows you to write the package in the Mathematica front end but not have to mark the cells individually and posted it as an answer to the other question:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/224851/9490